# FlexBox: In column-layout making the width match to widest

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following setup:

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="print-button" title="print" type="button"></button>
  <label for="print-button">Print Me!</label>
</div>
```

I wanted to use flex-box to place the button above the label, aligning them to the right of the parent element of the div, making the button the same width as the label.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
button{
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
label{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Works, as expected, but the button logically has it's own (in this case) smaller width.

If I set the container width to fit content and the align-items to stretch I get what I want width-wise but the container by default stays left. I could work around that with floats or positions, but that's not what I'm looking for. I also do not want to ad semantically unnecessary markup. I can (and probably will) use a grid, I just 'felt' that somehow this should be easily achieved with flex, I just couldn't find a way.

Here is a codePen: https://codepen.io/mdrei/pen/QWmMMeO

to play with, if needs be.

**Thank you for reading: I'd like to clarify: I'm not interested in other solutions to the problem, I have several in mind. I'm interested to find out if what I wanted is doable with flex-box.**

(Lets see if a moderator once again thinks he/she has to censor me because I say thank you)

Comment: No codepen link seen

Answer (score 0):

I think you will achieve it using display grid.

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: max-content;
}
```

Then just add float right if you want it to align to the right

Comment: Thank you, but as I stated in my question, I knew that. But I was wondering if there was a way to do it with flex. I feel I'm rather experienced with CSS, but especially with flex-box every now and then I'm surprised on how it works or doesn't. That's the reason I was asking the question.
And I'm surely not using float - I'd rather go for margin-right: 0 and margin-left: auto. As state in my quest in this case also flexbox with the container set to with: fit-content does the trick btw.

Answer (score 0):

Using only flex-box, you can add another div to achieve what you want:

(Unnecessary markup is added, I know, but maybe that could help you)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="another-container">
        <button id="print-button" title="print" type="button"></button>
        <label for="print-button">Print Me!</label>
    </div>
</div>

.another-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here is a codePen : https://codepen.io/Deirok/pen/MWVvrdG

Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks, You are right, I wasn't looking for that, but at least each answer not telling me how ignorant I am not to know an obvious solution within my parameters is an indication that at least I'm not totally missing it. :-)